# JSONP SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, jsonp

I have on a controller a function on codeigniter which gets and checks image for my templates.

I have place a id="template" just after my thumbnail bootstrap div id template works with my script code.

Currently when I select theme I get a firebug error

**Error Pop Up**

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
OK
{"image":"<img src=\\\"http:\/\/localhost\/codeigniter\/codeigniter-cms\/image\/templates\/default.png\\\" alt=\\\"\\\"\/>"}
```

**Controller Image Function**

```
public function template() {
  $this->load->helper('html');
  if (file_exists(FCPATH . 'image/templates/' . $this->configs->get('config_template') . '.png') == FALSE) {
    $img =  addslashes(img('image/no_image.png'));
    echo json_encode(array('image'=>$img));
  } else {
  if($this->input->post('config_template') !== FALSE) {
    $img = addslashes(img('image/templates/' . basename($this->input->post('config_template')) . '.png'));
    echo json_encode(array('image'=>$img));
   }
  }
}
```

**View**

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form-setting" class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-template"><?php echo $entry_template; ?></label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<select name="config_template" id="input-template" class="form-control">
<?php foreach ($templates as $template) { ?>
<?php if ($template == $config_template) { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $template; ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo $template; ?></option>
<?php } else { ?>
<option value="<?php echo $template; ?>"><?php echo $template; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</select>


<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="img-thumbnail">
<div id="template"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</form>

<script>
console.log('Jquery is working');
$('select[name="config_template"]').on('change', function () {
var template_name;
template_name = encodeURIComponent(this.value);
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'jsonp',
url: '<?=base_url('admin/setting/template');?>'  + '/',
data: { config_template: template_name
},
complete: function () {
$('.fa-spin').remove();
},
success: function (data) {
$('.fa-spin').remove();
$('#template').html(data.image);
},
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
}
});
})
</script>
```

Comment: You are outputting JSON. Not JSONP.

Comment: I all ready tried that but get error of `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/codeigniter/codeigniter-cms/%5C%22http://localhost/codeigniter/codeigniter-cms/image/templates/riwaka.png%5C%22"`

Comment: Sounds like you have "fixed" the problem with your image URL being wrong by preventing your script from parsing the data so it can't read the image URL in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Found out issue it was addslashes

old

```
public function template() {
  $this->load->helper('html');
  if (file_exists(FCPATH . 'image/templates/' . $this->configs->get('config_template') . '.png') == FALSE) {
    $img =  addslashes(img('image/no_image.png'));
    echo json_encode(array('image'=>$img));
  } else {
  if($this->input->post('config_template') !== FALSE) {
    $img = addslashes(img('image/templates/' . basename($this->input->post('config_template')) . '.png'));
    echo json_encode(array('image'=>$img));
   }
  }
}
```

new

```
public function template() {
$this->load->helper('html');
if (file_exists(FCPATH . 'image/templates/' . $this->configs->get('config_template') . '.png') == FALSE) {
$img = img('image/no_image.png');
echo json_encode(array('image'=>$img));
}else
{
if($this->input->post('config_template') !== FALSE)
{
$img = img('image/templates/' . $this->input->post('config_template') . '.png');
echo json_encode(array('image'=>$img));
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are outputting JSON. Not JSONP. Change `dataType: 'jsonp',` to `dataType: 'json',`
2. Adding slashes to some HTML will break that HTML. You'll be putting `\` characters in your image URLs and making them wrong. Remove all uses of the `addslashes` function. `encode_json` will do all the escaping you need.